# Can't get express.js response

Tags: javascript, jquery, express

I'm trying to handle the server response in different ways depending on its content, but I can't even run things that are unrelated to the response data.

Here is my request in jQuery:

`function Register() {
    var form = $('#signup-form')
    $.post("http://localhost:3000/register", form.serialize(), (data) => console.log("1"))
        .done((data) => console.log("2"))
        .fail((data) => console.log("3"))
        .always((data) => console.log("4"));
 }`

In Express:

```
rota.post('/register', (req, res) => {
const name = req.body.name;
const age = req.body.age;
const pass = sha256(req.body.pass);
const request = new sql.Request();
request.query(`SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE username = '${name}') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) AS re`).then(
    result => {
        if (result.recordset[0].re == true) {
            console.log("usuário já registrado");
            res.send("1");
        } else {
            request.query(`INSERT INTO Usuario(username, userage, userpass) VALUES('${name}', '${age}', '${pass}')`);
        }
    }).catch(result => {})
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know how this `sql.Request` object works, but it seems a bit suspicious that the `else` part of the code never sends anything back into the response. Use `res.sendStatus(200)` at the very least if you just want to signify that it was successful.

Comment: @Jeto Should I insert this into the `else`? Also, I'm quite sure there's no problem with the `sql.Request`, at least with its `query()` method, because it executes both the `console.log()` and the next query, when it's the case.

Comment: Yes, you should send a response back in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Send status back** in order to complete the request or it will remain open. Insert a **400** status response in your **catch block** to let the front-end know that the request has failed and to enter the `fail()` function:

```js
request.query(`SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE username = '${name}') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) AS re`).then(
    result => {
        if (result.recordset[0].re == true) {
            console.log("usuário já registrado");
            res.send("1");
        } else {
            request.query(`INSERT INTO Usuario(username, userage, userpass) VALUES('${name}', '${age}', '${pass}')`);
            res.status(200).send();  // here add a status of 200 to signal success
        }
    }).catch(result => {
       res.status(400).send();  // send also a 400 status response to signal failure
    })
})
```